# Time comparison check against MySQL DATETIME stamp

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if it has been an hour since the last `datetime` stamp in MySQL. How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: I always prefer to store a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` for my database as its easier to manipulate within php side of things.

Comment: @RobertPitt - using UNIX_TIMESTAMP is not recommended.

Comment: @RobertPitt You will have trouble using `DATE_SUB` and its friends, I believe.

Comment: It also makes ad-hoc queries harder.

Comment: This is where `FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)` comes in :), I also said that I prefer to store **a** unix timestamp

Comment: @RobertPitt Oh yeah, my memory fails me again. Still, I stand by using the date types with MySQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is in MySQL using DATE_SUB (or DATE_ADD depending on your goals). For example:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Likewise you can replace "1 HOUR" with other things like "1 DAY" or "1 MINUTE" and so on. I always prefer to do date comparisons at the database level since presumably the dates are being stored in a common format and GMT offset.

Answer (score 3):

you could and probably should do this entire thing in mysql instead

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

you can find the difference between a datetime field and the current time using your query, and return the result as a row.

Comment: I didn't know you can do this, that's why I chose PHP.

Comment: So I would use Use `TIMEDIFF( CURTIME() , $dbDateTime )` right? Could I get an example?

Comment: you seem to still be using a php variable? you pull the db datetime field directly out of the database. something like SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), name_of_datetime_field) AS time_diff FROM table_name WHERE id = blah LIMIT 1 or some such. you would pull it in the same query that you were getting your datetime value out of the database to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) explains about date_diff for PHP >= 5.3 and some work around solutions for older version.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_time = strtotime($row->timestamp_col);
$age = 60 * 60;
if ($db_time < (time() - $age)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

This is unnecessarily broken down so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$now = time();

$dbDate = strtotime($row['datetime']);

if ($now > $dbDate + 3600) {
   // yes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the check into the query. Then you can use a MySQL date comparison and the PHP doesn't have to know or care.